# Use rooted android to capture all traffic on wan using monitor/promiscuous mode

Tags: wi-fi, rooting, root-access, networking

Before I begin, I've searched quite a lot and haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for.

I have a rooted Nexus 5 with Kali Nethunter installed.
It's very easy to capture all network traffic from my phone, however I would like to capture it using monitor/promiscuous mode. In other words, simply the traffic of anyone who is connected to my internet **using my phone**

So far, I've only been able to see what my own network activity, so is it possible to capture, let's say my laptop's network traffic using my phone if they're on the same network.

And by this, I don't mean to create a hotspot on my phone, make my laptop connect to it and capture it then.

hope I've made it clear enough.

**Edit**

My question isn't limited to Nexus 5. Any android supported phone which may be able to achieve this could work.

Comment: Updated information for any android device

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Any android device

Cyanogenmod provides you with an option to build your own Cyanogen-build and integrated kernel building. With this you can compile an compatible kernel for your phone with desirable features. Here's a [post](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/android-cyanogenmod-kernel-building-monitor-mode-any-android-device-with-wireless-adapter-0162943/) that walks you through the process.

*R̲e̲qu̲i̲r̲e̲m̲e̲n̲t̲s̲:*
Linux machine
USB cable
familiarity with basic commands

---

### For Nexus 5

**Approach 1:**

Kali NetHunter won't allow you to [use inbuilt WiFi card](http://www.nethunter.com/faq/) to perform packet capture.
Moreover most mobile WiFi cards does not support promiscuous/monitor mode.
You need to use external WiFi card(such as Alfa card/Tp-link Wln722n),
connect to USB OTG on Nexus 5 for packet injection, then you're all set.

*R̲e̲qu̲i̲r̲e̲m̲e̲n̲t̲s̲:*
kali NetHunter
Root previliges
Host-mode support
USB OTG adapter cable
External WiFi card

**Approach 2:**

No need to install Kali NetHunter/any custom ROM.
Android [PCAP capture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.kismetwireless.android.pcapcapture) app lets user to capture WiFi packets.
It is developed by Kismet wireless.
It does not require Root previliges even.

*R̲e̲qu̲i̲r̲e̲m̲e̲n̲t̲s̲:*
Host-mode support
USB OTG adapter cable
External WiFi card

---

### Other android devices,with Broadcom chipset

There's support only for Broadcom WiFi chipsets from this [group](https://code.google.com/p/bcmon/).
There's [bcmon](https://code.google.com/p/bcmon/downloads/list) android app to capture network (works on stock but rooted-android).
Only supported chipset (firmwares) are old BCM4329 and BCM4330 and there's been no development on official [bcmon blog](http://bcmon.blogspot.in/) since July 2013.
Other firmwares you may have to [compile the drivers](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwj5saPX6-LHAhUUVY4KHYmiDIA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.coresecurity.com%2Fsystem%2Ffiles%2Fcorelabs-Hacklu-2012-one-firmware.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE7C59VDg3L484lDdBJfzDKK9A4Zw&sig2=oeoxCKHMKfDOAYDpprdPzg) for it.
You may have to compile the drivers manually for it.
Nexus 7(2012), Samsung galaxy S2 have BCM4330 whose internal wifi is capable of monitor mode.
Also Motorola Xoom, Galaxy Tab, Nexus S, Nexus One have BCM4329 and known to support bcmon.

---

### Little Experiment

And then I started searching firwares and drivers for Samsung galaxy S2 and started testing with this old phone.

[image: airodump on monitor mode On my own network]

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation and external references. Exactly the answer I wanted, thank you.

Comment: @DaBaws Glad to be of help, There's more to come, I'm researching on it.

Comment: I'll be eager to learn more, appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the further experiment, actually I was having a look at this a couple days ago http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1940416 trying to use my friends' galaxy s2 to do the same, seems like it works out well.